# Elastic beanstalk - Rolling deployment issue. Unexpected downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

We just migrated our Elastic beanstalk environments from PHP 7.3 running on 64bit **Amazon Linux** to PHP 7.4 running on 64bit **Amazon Linux 2** and we are seeing the following errors:

- When deploying code to the environment with a Rolling deployment policy - we get a 3-4 seconds 502 bad gateway before servers starts working again. We did not see this downtime with previous generation of Linux.
- Also: Application load balancer clear all sessions and signs out all users even though stickiness is enabled with a Load balancer generated cookie. We did not see this stickiness-issue with previous generation of Linux.

Happening on both Apache and Nginx.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Any new insights on this? I just upgraded to Amazon Linux 2 and have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Bad Gateway issue, but I recently ran into this loss of sessions issue. The sessions are lost because Amazon Linux 2 now uses the PHP-FPM service through systemd to host PHP. Session tracking in the default PHP/ElasticBeanstalk configuration is done by the use of files in the /tmp directory. However, systemd's "PrivateTmp" feature is enabled, which creates a unique directory for the PHP-FPM service to use when running. As soon as the PHP-FPM service is stopped, systemd deletes this special "private" /tmp, which deletes all the session files.

Whenever PHP ElasticBeanstalk deploys a new version, this PHP-FPM service is stopped and restarted, resulting in the loss of sessions.

There are a couple options to address this issue:

-> Configure PHP to use something like memcached/redis/etc to manage sessions, instead of using the filesystem. This is probably the most secure solution.

Or,

-> Configure your Amazon Linux 2 ElasticBeanstalk instances to handle these session files in the /tmp directory proper, instead of the "private" tmp directory provided by systemd.

This can be achieved by adding the following post-deploy configuration script into your project under the path: **.platform/hooks/postdeploy/phpfpm_noprivatetmp.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# change PrivateTmp from true to false, then reload/restart the systemd service
sed -i 's/PrivateTmp=true/PrivateTmp=false/' /usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service

# wait a moment...
sleep 2
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

# wait a moment...
sleep 2
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

This will disable the "PrivateTmp" feature in systemd, causing the session files to be stored in the "real" /tmp directory where they won't get deleted automatically.  Deploying new versions of your site will no longer cause everyone to get logged out.